# Erro com With SQL (Presto,Athena)

Tags: sql

tudo bem? Eu estou tendo um problema com o With,
Estou tentando criar uma tabela agrupada com uma coluna não agrupada.

No caso eu estou tentando montar uma tabela com o total transacionado de cada grupo + total de todas as transações somadas

O erro que é: ***Column 'query.amount_group' not in GROUP BY clause***

```
WITH query (amount_group,payment_type,brand,installments,plano)
as
(select
        sum(transactions.amount) amount_group,
        transactions."payment_type" payment_type,
        transactions."card_brand" brand,
        transactions."installments" installments,
        case
            when plans."name_plan" like '%pro%' then 'Pro'
            else 'Standart' end Plano
    from "_self_service_data"."self_transactions" transactions
    left join
        (select "customer", max("name_plan") name_plan from "_self_service_data"."self_zoop_plans" group by 1)plans
    on transactions."id_seller" = plans."customer"
    where transactions."payment_type" <> 'commission' and transactions."created_at" between date '2020-02-01' and now()
    group by 2,3,4,5)
select query.*, sum(query.amount_group) from query
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar? :)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, coloquei um over() logo depois do sum(query.amount_group) para não agrupar